# Change taskbar menu in Tauri

Tags: window-managers, tauri

I'm using [Tauri](https://tauri.studio/) and would like to change the menu items shown when clicking my application in the taskbar using the right mouse button (Windows/Linux) or double click (MacOS).

For example Firefox shows "Open a New Window" and music players often show "Play/Pause" or "Next track" buttons. How to do that with Tauri?

I'm aware of `SystemTrayMenu` in Tauri, but that only seems to affect the system tray, not the task bar.

(What I mean by "taskbar": the line of application icons that you click to open them, and that usually indicate which ones are running. I think MacOS calls it Dock, in Windows it's at the bottom between start button and clock, and Linux isn't very homogeneous but in Ubuntu it's vertically on the left by default. I do *not* mean the system tray of usually smaller icons that are almost always next to the clock, that are usually more like background services. I.e. I mean where your browser usually shown up, not where your VPN usually shows up.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tauri does not support this at the moment (2022-06-27). You may file a feature request.